# align labels and textfields

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to distribute space 50% for both `label` and `input` types with the following DOM content or the naive approach of creating separate tags for the label or the input.

**DOM in question.** how to approach with following DOM

```html
<label for="first">First Name: <input id="first" type="text"/></label>
<label for="last">Last Name: <input id="last" type="text"/></label>
<label for="email">Email: <input id="email" type="text"/></label>
```

**Visual Expectation**

Labels 50% width

Input 50% width aligned on their left side

---

**Naive approach** separate labels and inputs

```
<label for="first">First Name: </label><input id="first" type="text"/>
<label for="last">Last Name: </label><input id="last" type="text"/>
<label for="email">Email: </label><input id="email" type="text"/>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    width: 50%;
}
input {
    width: 50%
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an old school solution you can float the input to the right:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<label>First Name: <input id="first" type="text"/></label>
<label>Last Name: <input id="last" type="text"/></label>
<label>Email: <input id="email" type="text"/></label>
```

You can style each label as a grid with two columns:

```css
label {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<label>First Name: <input id="first" type="text"/></label>
<label>Last Name: <input id="last" type="text"/></label>
<label>Email: <input id="email" type="text"/></label>
```

Comment: thanks, I appreciate, can you please append an answer in non-grid or non-flex based approach, I guess for that I've to separate out label and input and remove input nesting.

Comment: For flex answer, I would go with the answer by @V.Volkov

Comment: sorry, i fixed the comment, non grid and non flex, pure vanilla css. I like the given answer, but want an appended solution

Comment: @AppDeveloper: flex and grid are "*pure vanilla css,*" why do you believe you can't make use of up-to-date layout options?

Comment: Thank you for both approaches, I'm learning so both perspectives helping me adapt to new layout options, help me with the grid please, you applied grid to the label and two 50% columns so those columns are the Text node and the input nodes as the children?

Comment: Indeed - two columns - one text & one input

Comment: Incidentally, if the `<input>` is nested within the `<label>` then the `for` attribute of the `<label>` (`HTMLLabelElement.htmlFor`) isn't needed (it's not invalid, or a problem so long as it has the right value for the nested `<input>`, but it's not necessary and can be removed as a minor bandwidth saving).

Answer (score 1):

Both variants:

```css
label {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
label > * {
  flex-basis:50%;
}
```

```html
<label for="first">First Name: <input id="first" type="text"/></label>
<label for="last">Last Name: <input id="last" type="text"/></label>
<label for="email">Email: <input id="email" type="text"/></label>
```

```css
label, input {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<label for="first">First Name: </label><input id="first" type="text"/>
<label for="last">Last Name: </label><input id="last" type="text"/>
<label for="email">Email: </label><input id="email" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  width: 600px;
  background: #ccc;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="first">First Name: </label><input id="first" type="text" />
  <label for="last">Last Name: </label><input id="last" type="text" />
  <label for="email">Email: </label><input id="email" type="text" />
</div>
```

`display: inline-block;` let's you define the dimensions of the element without adding a line break after the element like `display: block;` would. `box-sizing: border-box;` let's you include the borders of the input element in its width (without this the actual width of the input would be over 50% and would cause a line break).

In case you wanted them to be on separate lines with 50% width, simply change `inline-block` to `block`, which will add the line break.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..
Nest your label and inputs in side a table and use width of 50% or 50vw for